# asp.net Dynamic Data filtering view

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-dynamic-data

I use asp.net dynamic data to show the contents of a few tables that I have in a sql server database and it's pretty cool. Apart from that, I'm trying to do one other thing.

say there is a table

```
CustomerComplaints
    - some fields
    - CustomerName
    - ComplaintType
    - ComplaintDate
    - other fields
```

I want to show a view with Top Complaining Customer

so I created a view

```
 select CustomerName, count(*) ComplaintCount from CustomerComplaints group by CustomerName
```

but I also want to be able to pass in an optional `AfterDate` and `BeforeDate` to filter on ComplaintDate to do my Top Compalining Customer view.

What's a good way to go about to do this without creating a page very specific for this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could pass parameters to your query and use this:

```
SELECT CustomerName, count(*) ComplaintCount 
FROM CustomerComplaints 
WHERE ComplaintDate BETWEEN @AfterDate AND @BeforeDate
GROUP BY CustomerName
```

And then set default values for those parameters as whatever the min and max are for that column's data type (if it's `datetime2`, the values would be `0001-01-01` and `9999-12-31`).  This way, if you don't pass parameters explicitly, the default values won't filter your results at all.